# Calling a shared library function without parameters

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-shared-libraries

I'm using a shared library with jenkins 2. Meaning, I'm utilizing the ability to reuse some of the pipeline code I'm writing in various stages.

here is an example of module **vars/utils.groovy**

```
def set_virtual_env() {
    sh """
    chmod 777 virt_run_pytest.sh
    chmod 777 install_python_venv.sh

    pip install -U setuptools
    bash install_python_venv.sh
    """
}
```

When trying to execute it in a pipeline script, it gets failed with the following error:

```
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: set_virtual_env for class: groovy.lang.Binding
```

I suspect that the reason for that is because I'm not passing any variable to this function and as a result it's not instantiated correctly.

So the actual question might be, "**How can I call a shared library function that does not needs arguments**"?

Comment: Can you provide your pipeline or at least the part where you call the method?

Comment: I found the reason. thank you. I'll edit my question :)

Comment: Please put answers in answers - don't edit the question to put the answer there.

Answer (score 1):

I was calling the object and not the method. meaning, I called it:

```
utils.set_virtual_env
```

Instead of

```
utils.set_virtual_env()
```